# What limitations on campaign contributions, direct and indirect, exist in the US?

Tags: united-states, finance, elections

I know that an individual can't donate more than $2,800, but, apparently, it is [not](https://www.fec.gov/data/receipts/individual-contributions/?committee_id=C00652065&two_year_transaction_period=2020&min_date=01%2F01%2F2019&max_date=12%2F31%2F2020) strictly followed (click on "amount"). Besides, there's a thing called the "Citizens United" Supreme Court ruling that, if I remember it correctly, allows unlimited donations to so-called political action committees (PACs), including those that are affiliated with particular candidates. Could those contributions be anonymous? In sum, what limitations exist on campaign donations in the US, including indirect ones through PACs and, whatever it means, Super-PACs?

Comment: You may want to narrow the focus of your question. The answer will vary between federal and state elections, and even then, there will be a different answer for each state. The rules are different for humans than they are for business entities, which are different from the rules for nonprofit organizations, which are different from the rules for labor unions. The rules are different for contributions to a candidate than they are to political party, and those are different from the rules for contributions to a PAC, which are different from the rules for a super PAC.

Comment: @bdb484 I mean federal elections. Other than that, yes, I would like to hear a brief summary of all relevant limitations, if it's not burdensome. Or maybe you could offer a good article in a reliable source on the issue